# What type of input should I give to this function?

Tags: solidity

```
  struct khatian{
        uint64 khatianiId;
        bytes32 plotHash;
        uint16 percentOwn;
        bytes32 buyFrom;
        bytes32[] sellTo;
        uint16[] sellPercentage;
        uint[] ownerArray;
        uint16[] perOwnerPercentage;
        bool isExist;
    }
```

```
function addKhatianFromOld(uint64 _khatianiId, bytes32 _plotHash, uint16 _percentOwn, bytes32 _buyFrom, uint[] _user, uint16[] _percentage) public{
        require(msg.sender == contarctOwner, "Sender is not authorized");
        require(plotMapping[_plotHash].isExist == true, "Plot doesn't exist");
        
        bytes32 khatianHash = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_khatianiId, _plotHash));
        
        require(khatianMapping[khatianHash].isExist != true, "Khatian already exists");
        require(khatianMapping[_buyFrom].isExist, "previous Khatian doesn't exist");
        require(khatianMapping[_buyFrom].percentOwn >= _percentOwn, "Not enough land to sell");
        for(uint j = 0; j< _user.length; j++){
             require(userMapping[_user[j]].isExist == true, "User's NID doesn't exist");
        }
```

This are my code snippet. I getting this error

```
 ''Error: expected array value (argument=null, value="1", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.5.0)''
```

What type of data should I give input here? specially in bytes32_buyFrom, uint[] _user, uint16[] _percentage?

I tried to give address and other string as input

Answer (score 0):

Add memory / calldata keyword after declaring uint[] just like this `uint[] memory _user` and  `uint16[] memory _percentage` let me know if it works

Comment: No it's still not working. Can you give me an example how I can give input for these type of datatype?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you must change the signature method adding the where memorized the data passed in input. In detail, you can consider that adding in memory the arrays.
Insomuch, change your method signature method in this way:

```
function addKhatianFromOld(uint64 _khatianiId, bytes32 _plotHash, uint16 _percentOwn, bytes32 _buyFrom, uint[] memory _user, uint16[] memory _percentage) public{
  // your logic
}
```

To reply about your question:

- In bytes32 parameter, in this function, you must give a format bytes32 from a string. You can see my answer to this [thread](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/52859/example-for-type-bytes32-in-solidity/129436#129436) for convert string to bytes32;
- In uint[] array parameter, you must filled it with integer number starting from a maximum range value: 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935
  (2**256);
- In uint16[] array parameter, you must filled it with integer number starting from a maximum range value:
  65536
  (2**16)

In following attach an example of request with vainput